# Test android subscriptions with grace period

Tags: android, in-app-subscription

As I can see on this page:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/faster-renewals-for-test-subscriptions.html

in order to test subscriptions with grace period I need to perform these steps:

1. Sign up for an in-app subscription using payment method "Test instrument - always accepts".  Subscription starts.
2. Go to Play store and change payment method to "Test instrument - always declines".
3. Wait 5 munites. On the next renewal payment declined. Enter grace period.
4. Wait < 5 minutes.
5. Go to Play store and change payment method to "Test instrument - always accepts".
    Subscription recovered.

The question is - how can I perform steps 2 and 5 (Go to Play store and change payment method to "Test instrument - aways ...")?

I didn't see in Play Store on device anything related to "Test card", even logged in with the test account.
The only place when I can select "Test card - always accepts or declines" is pop-up window after starting subscription flow.

Answer (score 3):

Go to play store, choose your test account, go to subscriptions page your test purchase should be there click on it click on Update under payment method now you can choose "always decline"